# Rocksmith 2014: 3/4 guitar + pitch shift?

Tags: rocksmith-2014

I want to play Rocksmith 2014. Unfortunately, the guitar I'm getting is a travel guitar with a ~3/4 size fretboard and a non-standard tuning. Users of this guitar have said that getting the standard EADGBE tuning is finicky if not impossible, so that's not an option. However, I've been wondering: could I pitch shift the guitar back down via software or hardware in order for it to work correctly with Rocksmith? I'd love to give it a try, but I don't want to spend a ton of money on the game and the hardware (if required) if I'm not sure that it'll work.

Comment: Since the guitar has to go through the hardware audio interface made for Ubisoft, I doubt you can do much to change the signal (someone correct me if I'm wrong).
May I ask what kind of guitar is so difficult to get to standard tuning?

Comment: Couldn't you get a pedal or something that sits between the guitar and the interface? The guitar I'm talking about is [this one](http://www.lapstick.com/travel-guitar.php).

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZhM21M8JGE), maybe.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't think of using a pedal, since all the processing can be done on the computer now, but yeah, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible.